# Vuex store action from Promise to async/await

Tags: promise, async-await, action, vuex, store

Currently I use `promises` in the store actions but want to convert it into `async/await`. This is an example of the store action with promises:

```js
fetchActiveWorkspace (context, workspaceID) {
    if (workspaceID) {
      return this.$axios.get(`@api-v01/workspaces/workspace/${workspaceID}`)
        .then(response => {
          context.commit('setActiveWorkspace', response.data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          throw err
        })
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve(true)
    }
  },
```

This `fetchActiveWorkspace` action is resolved in components because it returns `promise`. How can I convert this code snippet into a `async/await` structure and use it in components?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would try to translate it; take into account that as I have no access to the original code in full context, I cannot try it first-hand to make sure it works; but still, this is how you can use `async/await` with promises.

```js
// 1. Mark the function as `async` (otherwise you cannot use `await` inside of it)
async fetchActiveWorkspace(context, workspaceID) {
    if (workspaceID) {

      // 2. Call the promise-returning function with `await` to wait for result before moving on.
      // Capture the response in a varible (it used to go as argument for `then`)
      let response = await this.$axios.get(`@api-v01/workspaces/workspace/${workspaceID}`);
      context.commit('setActiveWorkspace', response.data);
    }

    // 3. I don't think this is necessary, as actions are not meant to return values and instead should be for asynchronous mutations.
    else {
      return true;
    }
}
```

You can surround the function's body with `try/catch` in case you want to capture and handle exceptions. I didn't add it in order to keep things simple and because your promise-based code will just capture and re-throw the exception, without doing anything else.